# str_replace - with the replacement of the figures

Tags: str-replace

**Hello,**
Is there a solution to this problem?

```
$vowels_1 = array("1","12","11");
$vowels_2 = array("One","Twelve","Eleven");
$onlyconsonants = str_replace($vowels_1, $vowels_2, "11");
echo $onlyconsonants;
```

Result = **OneOne**

It is supposed to be = **Eleven**

*Is there a solution?*

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple, Just swap you `$vowels`

```
$vowels_1 = array("11","12","1");
$vowels_2 = array("Eleven","Twelve","One")
```